# ASP.NET: MVC Site not matching route after POST redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms

### Problem

I have a legacy ASP.net web forms project that I'm attempting to slowly convert to an MVC website. The old site was built in multiple projects -- see below for an example. When a user is unauthenticated, they are sent to a login project (webforms) and then redirected back to the new MVC project.

```
  website.com (IIS site host)
    - /loginproject/login.aspx   (project 1 - auth, built in webforms)
    - /product1/*.aspx           (project 2 - built in webforms)
    - /product2/ ... /productX/

    - /mvcsite/* (new MVC project -- this is what I'm trying to get to)
```

Both `loginproject` and `product1` were built in webforms and work by sending POST data between each other, and using the session system. I can't merge just these projects, they're individually complex and it would take far too long. I also can't set up a new login page in MVC and just have the user sign in there (or twice) -- business decision.

While I can get the form data back, MVC is unable to actually match a route. I can't actually load the session back up and continue.

#### TL;DR: Give me a routing example:

```
GET > website.com/mvc/page (Not logged in)
Redirect > website.com/loginproject/login.aspx (Login page)
GET > website.com/loginproject/redirect.aspx?page=/mvcsite/page (Redirect page for form)
POST > /mvcsite/page (Form data has session info)
```

Comment: I understand that you want the Webforms session to be validated in the new MVC project so as not to have to request authentication from the user again. I had this same case in a project, but I am afraid I could not "make the session exist in two different applications", the solution was to send the session data to the database from APP1 and redirect to APP2 with a token by GET , that APP2 form validates the session from the same database and allocates the session, that was my solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the main problem is not passing the data; the POST redirect is sending to the new URL and the form data is there. The problem is that the MVC site stops recognizing the route after the redirect.